# Docker error localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

My development team and I have been having the hardest time getting our Ruby on Rails application to dockerize. All tutorials and answers out there seem to be years old and thus outdated.

After a few days of researching things and trying multiple techniques, we are finally finding answers. So, this post is to ask the most recent question and provide the answer we got.

In a new Ruby on Rails application running Ruby 2.7.0 and Rails 6.0.3.4, we would be able to run a rails server and get the standard Ruby screen at `localhost:3000`. But, after dockerizing the app and going to `localhost:8000` as that is supposedly the default port for a docker image, we would get an error stating that the localhost didn't send any data.

This is the question, what is causing this to occur? We tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` and even the local machine's name that we got by running `hostname` in the terminal. None of these worked listening on port `3000` or port `8000`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that we came up with for this problem is that the app was still saying that the information requests should be coming from port `3000` even though docker was looking at port `8000`. So, we went into `config/puma.rb` and changed the code like this:

```
-port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
+port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 8000 }
```

Basically, if you are having this same issue, look in the `puma.rb` file for the line that designates port `3000` and change it to port `8000`. Once that happened, we were in business.

NOTE: The - and + signs in the code above are from the git repository showing that the first line was deleted and the second line added. Those symbols should not be in the actual code.

Good luck and happy codeing!